# Non-consciously VS Un-consciously

Tags: grammaticality, semantic-roles

I have seen the following sentences in standard English study materials

> **1**. Native English speakers acquire the language non-consciously.
>
> **2**. Native English speakers acquire the language un-consciously

I have asked a professor which one was right He replied that both were correct.Some otherprofessor replied that we acquire our native language non-consciously but not un-consciously because we can not do anything when we are unconscious

I would like to know which one of the above sentences is/are correct semantically and grammatically.

Comment: The second teacher is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many grammar websites, including [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/consciously), list "**unconsciously**" as the antonym of consciously.

Even though nonconscious is a word, and is synonymous to unconscious, I personally have not commonly seen its use, so I'd suggest to make the safe choice.

Answer (score 0):

"unholy" means in some way opposed to holy virtues, but "non-holy" just means "not Holy".

"Non-" is implying just negation or absence of something (rather than the opposite of it, as expressed by un).